# Optimizing access time

Tags: optimization

Suppose I have 6 files namely F1,F2.. F6 with 100, 200, 50, 80, 120, 150 records respectively. Does the order of storing the files optimize access time? If so, then which order is preferable ?

According to me, the order of storing shouldn't affect the access time. Because, if we store the files as with largest record first and then so on till the lowest one, it will have the same effect as stored from lower number of records to a higher number!

Comment: No, not unless you still use magnetic tape as your storage medium.

Comment: suppose i use magnetic tapes then what happens ?

Comment: Sorry my irony didn't translate.  Modern storage systems are direct access, and the file system caches most meta data, so the main time cost is when you incur a cache-miss and phys I/O is needed to access the info.  The difference in seek time is relatively trivial.  This is not the case with a serial storage medium where block to block access will dominate.